# Realm and Threading

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, realm, realm-android

Пишу проект. В качестве БД использую *Realm*. Это первый опыт с этой бд, поэтому за вопрос прошу не линчевать.
Итак, к примеру, в качестве модели бд есть класс (все упрощенно, так как хочу передать суть вопроса как можно яснее):

```
public class QuoteText extends RealmObject {
    private long id;
    private String quoteText;
    ...
}
```

Для изолирования слоя работы с этой бд я решила применить обобщенный вариант паттерна *Repository*. Написала интерфейс:

```
public interface QuoteRepository {
    List<QuoteText> getListOfQuoteText();
}
```

И класс, реализующий этот интерфейс:

```
public class QuoteDataRepository implements QuoteRepository {
    private final Realm realm;  
    @Override
    public List<QuoteText> getListOfQuoteText() {
        return realm.where(QuoteText.class).findAll();
    }
}
```

Соответственно во фрагменте для получения списка `QuoteText` из бд:

```
QuoteDataRepository quoteDataRepository = new QuoteDataRepository();
List<QuoteText> quoteTexts = quoteDataRepository.getListOfQuoteText();
```

Все бы ничего, но хотелось бы все эти запросы делать не в UI потоке. Как засунуть это все в другой поток? (Особенно интересно: можно ли совместить способы асинхронных запросов предлагаемые Realm (назнчаение слушателей, или запрос с использованием `onSuccess()`, `onError()` и прочее) и изоляцию слоя работы с бд).

Спасибо за помощь!

Правка: важен момент именно абстракции кода работы с бд и реализации асинхронных запросов.

Comment: Вы не сможете полностью абстрагироваться от Realm в своем фрагменте, потому что результат выборки будет `RealmResults` - с ним вам и работать. Трансформировать как то его в `List` бессмысленно и беспощадно - теряется сама суть работы с БД, особенно учитывая, что в Realm выборка `RealmResults` связана с данными в БД и изменения данных в выборке изменяет данные в самой БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Красивее всего получится если вы будете соединять Realm + RxJava + Retrolambda.

Например вот такое может получиться:

```
public Observable<List<VkPost>> getFeedVkPostsSortedAsync(String field, Sort order) {
    return mRealm.where(VkPost.class)
            .equalTo(VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FEED, true)
            .equalTo(VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FAVORITES, true)
            .findAllSortedAsync(field, order)
            .asObservable()
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
            .filter(RealmResults::isValid)
            //опционально и на всякий случай отвязываем объекты от реалма и
            //возвращаем обычные объекты в обычном листе
            .flatMap(realmResults -> Observable.just(mRealm.copyFromRealm(realmResults)));
}
```

Данный Observable, запущенный из основного потока выполнит запрос в БД асинхронно, отсеет объекты не удовлетворяющие двум условиям значений полей объектов (`VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FEED`, `VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FAVORITES`) и проверит что объекты возвращаемые полностью готовы для использования. И будет эмитить новую выборку при каждом изменении в ней.

Comment: Вот это красота! Правда с Rx я пока на "Вы". Но Вы меня убедили получше с ней познакомиться)

Comment: @V.Zatchepina, вы не пожалеете) Rx крут. Правда чтобы всё было нормально подписываться лучше не во фрагменте, т.к. он может быть уничтожен, а где-то в другом месте. Например в синглтоне. Взять, например, либу mosby и пилить MVP. В презентере подписываетесь и шлёте данные во View (фрагмент), который их отображает.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас ещё один вариантик, продумаю и если заработает - отпишусь. При другом исходе - буду осваивать RxJava, так как код ну просто прекрасен:)

Comment: @V.Zatchepina Это решение, как бы код ни был прекрасен, так же не абстрагирует вас от `RealmResults`, если вы именно этого добиваетесь - результат работы метода будет типа `RealmResults`. Эта абстракция вообще бессмысленна и единственная ее способность - ухудшить взаимодействие с БД.

Comment: Эм...RealmResults<CustomObject> Спокойно приводится к List<CustomObject>. И можно работать с этими объектами как с обычными...ну во всяком случае так работало)

Comment: @pavlofff, согласен про ненужность абстракции через репозиторий, если вы об этом) А от RealmResults уйти просто - добавил в ответ одну строку.

Comment: @V.Zatchepina, не совсем верно то, что можно работать как с обычным `List`. Например при попытке что-то сделать с объектами из этого списка вне основного потока будет падение - т.к. всё в RealmResults - managed объекты и действия над ними будут сразу в БД писаться. К тому же в основном потоке что может вызвать проблемы с отзывчивостью. Как получить отвязанные от реалма объекты, т.е. настоящий `List` - добавил в ответ последней строкой

Comment: @V.Zatchepina Сама цель абстрагироваться от БД, потому, что вдруг буду использовать другую БД несколько странная. На переупаковку в "нейтральные" объекты может понадобится существенное количество времени и ресурсов, при этом часть функциональности прямой выборки теряется. Чтобы уменьшить количество кода, вы можете написать класс-helper, который будет иметь методы для запросов в Realm и держать с ней подключение. В сами методы передавать только параметры запроса, а получать готовую выборку. как аналогичный для SQLite - `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, что развеяли моё заблуждение.

Comment: @pavlofff, да, спасибо, собственно все свои ошибки и нюансы я теперь поняла. Абстракции не будет, точно не с этой бд.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы говорили про "странность" желания абстракции. Просто, понимаете, мне кажется, код смотрится лучше, он более пригоден к повторному использованию если есть такое разделение на "блоки".

Answer (score 4):

У *Realm* есть возможность создавать [асинхронные запросы](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries). Для этого нужно вместо `findAll()` вызывать `findAllAsync()`.

Поправлю Ваш интерфейс, потому что оба этих метода возвращают не `List`, а `RealmResults` - это объект стандарта [`Future`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

```
public interface QuoteRepository {
    RealmResults<QuoteText> getListOfQuoteTextAsync();
}
```

Для того, чтобы получить уведомление об окончании загрузки нужно [добавить подписку](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#register-a-callback) на экземпляр `RealmResults`:

```
RealmResults<QuoteText> result = quoteDataRepository.getListOfQuoteTextAsync();
result.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<User> results) {
        // метод будет вызван, когда запрос будет выполнен или при обновлении данных
    }
});
```

Помимо этого, можно [убедиться в завершении загрузки](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#check-if-the-query-has-completed) вызвав метод `isLoaded()`:

```
if (result.isLoaded()) {
    // данные загружены
}
```

#### Получение результата

Для работы с результатами запросов (в том числе асинхронными) *Realm* предоставляет [специализированные адаптеры](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters), которые нужно добавить в зависимости в *build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
}
```

После этого *нужно создать наследника* от `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, который будет работать с Вашим `ViewHolder`. Продемонстрирую использование на примере из [документации](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances)

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        // установка Вашего адаптера для RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
                                    // установка результата асинхронного запроса
                                    quoteDataRepository.getListOfQuoteTextAsync()));

        // ...

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

В общем случае для получения (и отображения) результата внутри `Fragment`/`Activity` нужно осуществить подписку на `RealmResults`. Сделать это нужно *именно в вызывающем коде* для возможности отписаться от уведомлений (так как никто кроме вызывающего кода не знает, когда запрос для него уже неактуален). Этот вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults results;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
        results = quoteDataRepository.getListOfQuoteTextAsync();
        // добавление подписки на получение результата
        results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onChange(RealmResults<User> results) {
                 // метод будет вызван, когда запрос будет выполнен или при обновлении данных
                 // здесь можно обновлять экран или делать другой полезный код
             }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        // при уничтожении фрагмента нужно отписаться от уведомлений
        results.removeChangeListeners(); 
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да да это я знаю. Просто до меня не доходит одно: если я эти запросы пишу в классе репозитория в async, то вызывая этот метод во фрагменте, метод вернет ноль, так и не дождавшись возвращения реального результата. Изначально я мешала реализацию бд с фрагментом, чтобы пощупать realm. Но в действительности мне надо сделать так, чтобы метод класса репозитория возвращал не пустой список, а дожидался данных при том, чтобы фрагмент понятия не имел о том, с какой бд он работает (так сказать ни строчки кода с realm во фрагменте). Уф... надеюсь я не сильно Вас запутала.

Comment: Метод вернёт не null, а RealmResults. На этот объект Вам нужно подписаться, чтобы Вам сообщили, когда данные будут загружены. В этот момент можно будет ими пользоваться

Comment: Ох...простите мои объяснения, но я повторюсь: я знаю, что вернет не null. Запускаю app, создается фрагмент, он создает экземпляр репозитория и вызывает его метод в котором идет запрос к бд. В итоге получаю список данных (Почему пишу List<Object> - чтобы не было кода, связанного с Realm). Если пустить все в главном потоке все работает отлично. Но если писать запрос async, то естественно возвращается нулевой список, так как данные еще не вернулись.   (продолжение смотрите ниже...)

Comment: Для того, чтобы подписаться на RealmResults, код напишется во фрагменте (а не в классе репозиторий), а этого мне не надо. В голову не приходит как подписаться избегая кода во фрагменте. Уже думаю может в аргументах метода репозитория адаптер передавать и в слушателе его обновить...но это тоже вариантик так себе. Надеюсь вы меня поняли...Или я вас не понимаю)

Comment: @V.Zatchepina, добавил раздел про работу с адаптерами в _Realm_. Посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Изначально я так и делала. Просто на данный момент стояла задача именно найти способ абстрагирования от данной реализации бд, чтобы можно было заменить на другую при необходимости.

Comment: @V.Zatchepina, вопрос ведь звучит не об абстрагировании, а об асинхронных запросах. Почему Вы не приняли мой ответ? Если у вас возник другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно

Comment: Прошу прощения, ни в коем случае не хотела Вас расстроить. Возможно, я не особо хорошо изложила вопрос, так как суть вопроса осталась в скобках последнего приложения, а именно: сделать асинхронный запрос и сделать так, чтобы ни строчки кода realm не было вне класса репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта статья(-и) дала(-и) ответы на все мои вопросы! Спасибо автору!

> https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f#.9735g4ojc